# display post count on single posts via post view count plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/baw-post-views-count/

i'm installed and active "Post Views Count" plugin but when i'm use shortcode [post_view] like this, it's doesn't woek....
i cant use it on single.php :

```
<?php bawpvc_views_sc(); ?>
```

Warning: Missing argument 1 for bawpvc_views_sc(), called in ... \single.php on line 14 and defined in ...plugins\baw-post-views-count\bawpv.php on line 55

** **Please NOTE** :**

thanks to all ..

to show post views on your single.php add this code :

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[post_view]"); ?>
```

i founded it here :

[how to use “Post Views Count” plugin on template?](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-use-%E2%80%9Cpost-views-count%E2%80%9D-plugin-on-template?replies=5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you already answered your own question but the answer is in what you've written above...

Use `<?php echo do_shortcode("[post_view]"); ?>`

instead of `<?php bawpvc_views_sc(); ?>`